# How to calculate checksum of UDP packet embedded inside IP packet

Tags: c++, networking, tcp, udp

I have a UDP packet which is embedded inside IP packet and not able to calculate the checksum of UDP properly but I can correctly find the CHecksum of IP. Can someone help how the UDP checksum is found.

[45 00 00 53 00 80 00 00 40 11 **66 16** 0A 00 00 03 0A 00 00 02] CA B1 CA B1 00 3F DF A5

The bits enclosed in bracket is IP packet and the checksum is given in bold.

```
**UDP Packet**
CA B1 Source port
CA B1 Destination port
00 3F Length
DF A5 Checksum
```

Here how the checksum "DF A5" came. I did 16 bit addition and took the 1s complement but still not getting the value. Whether I need to consider IP header also to calculate the Checksum of UDP

Comment: I punched "how to calculate UDP checksum" into a search engine and it was explained in the [first hit](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~mlsichit/Teaching/407/Resources/udpChecksum.html) that I got.

Comment: There is even an RFC about this. Why are you asking here?

Comment: This may help you (In second part it has implementation) http://www.roman10.net/how-to-calculate-iptcpudp-checksumpart-1-theory/